# Protocol Oriented Programming: General struct of type Any in Protocol + introspection valueForKey()

Tags: swift, struct, protocols

When setting a protocol for a struct with type Any, I expect it would be possible to set the type of a struct to what I want. The following code is pasted from a playground I made:

```
import Foundation

// MyStruct does not conform to protocol StructProtocol
// With a general type for struct, like Any, AnyStruct or just Struct, this should be possible
struct MyStruct: StructProtocol {
  var thisStruct: ThisStruct
  var thatStruct: ThatStruct
}

struct ThisStruct {
  var someString: String
}

struct ThatStruct {
  var someOtherString: String
  var andAnotherString: String
}

protocol StructProtocol {
  // Should be able to put Any / AnyStruct / Struct here for a generic struct
  var thisStruct: Any {get}
  var thatStruct: Any {get}
}

extension StructProtocol {
  func saySomething() {
    let firstMirror = Mirror(reflecting: self.thisStruct)
    let secondMirror = Mirror(reflecting: self.thatStruct)

    for structVar in firstMirror.children {
      print(self.thisStruct.valueForKey(structVar))
    }

    for structVar in secondMirror.children {
      print(self.thatStruct.valueForKey(structVar))
    }
  }
}

var thisStruct = ThisStruct(someString: "Hi")
var thatStruct = ThatStruct(someOtherString: "Hello", andAnotherString: "Hola")

var myStruct = MyStruct(thisStruct: thisStruct, thatStruct: thatStruct)
myStuct.saySomething()

// Should output "Hi", "Hello" and "Hola"
```

Today there is no generic struct type the protocol can refer to. One have to set the struct vars to exactly the same type as the protocol. Maybe I misunderstood this and there is a way to accomplish what Im looking for, but so far I have not found an answer.

I think it would be great to do this in Swift, so if there is no way of accomplishing this, Ill post it as a feature request in the Swift project, but first Ill run this by you experts here in StackOverflow.

So the question is: Is this possible in some other way?

Comment: what real world problem are you trying to solve? mirrors aren't real world solutions to problems really...

Comment: This could be used for parsing JSON for example. The mirroring bit is not the main problem, it is setting a generic struct in the protocol, and not being able to use a specific struct in the struct using that protocol.

Comment: what is a generic struct? without mirroring, what would you do with it? why aren't you requiring a protocol which contains other things conforming to some other protocol?

Comment: When using a general struct instead of a specific struct in the protocol, that said protocol could be used for a lot of different structs. And the mirroring is just some dummy code, its not the introspection thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you describe using multiple protocols. The issue with what you're asking for is how you would use these generic structs (if they don't conform to some other protocol or take some generic parameters) - you'd have to cast them and then the whole point of the generic nature you ask for is lost.

So, you can do something like:

```
protocol InnerProtocol {
    func printChildren()
}

protocol StructProtocol {
    var inner1: InnerProtocol {get}
    var inner2: InnerProtocol {get}
}


struct MyStruct : StructProtocol {
    var inner1: InnerProtocol
    var inner2: InnerProtocol
}

struct ThisStruct : InnerProtocol {
    var someString: String

    func printChildren() {
        print(someString)
    }
}

struct ThatStruct : InnerProtocol {
    var someOtherString: String
    var andAnotherString: String

    func printChildren() {
        print(someOtherString)
        print(andAnotherString)
    }
}

extension StructProtocol {

    func saySomething() {
        inner1.printChildren()
        inner2.printChildren()
    }
}


var thisStruct = ThisStruct(someString: "Hi")
var thatStruct = ThatStruct(someOtherString: "Hello", andAnotherString: "Hola")

var myStruct = MyStruct(inner1: thisStruct, inner2: thatStruct)
myStruct.saySomething()
```

Comment: I have done the same as this already in an app Im working on, but when doing it the way I described in the question, the code could be moved from the struct and into the protocol instead. That way the printChildren function could be implemented there instead of in each of the structs themselves. This is an answer to the specific problem, not an answer to the generic problem ;)

Comment: only when using introspection, otherwise you don't know the actual content of the inner structs

Comment: but you need to know the contents to work with them, that's either by introspection or by some interface spec - the protocol

Comment: Yes, ofcoz, but again, that was not the question. Introspection in Swift is very limited at the moment, but better support is on the way, or at least requests for better support are made. I asked a generic question, just to see if there was a way to handle the generic structs in protocols today, so I do not ask for something thats already implemented when posting the request on swift.org

Comment: the generic way you want doesn't exist, and i wouldn't expect it to be added to the language based on how it could be used, but it could well be a very interesting discussion to have

Comment: When using classes instead of structs, the generic AnyClass can be used in a protocol. And since Apple encourages use of values instead of classes, and since Protocol Oriented Programming is so powerful, combining the strength of protocols and the struct value would be nice.